# Limiting words count in model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Meets model meet.rb with one attribute called tags.
User inputs them with single form_for.
Question would be: how can I limit in my model that if user inputs more that 3 words, he would get an error message.
Or if you can show me solution with javascript it would be nice too.
Thank you!

Comment: Would tags be passed in as an array or a string?

Comment: Please show your controller and model code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably write custom validation method in `Meet` model:

```
class Meet < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...
  validate :no_more_than_three_tags
  # ...
  def no_more_than_three_tags
    errors.add(:tags, 'more than three words') if tags.split(/\W/).count > 3
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to go off of, I would think you have a method with an argument, tags. If so, you might do something like this.

```
 def method(tags)
   array = tags.split(" ")
   raise ArgumentError.new("More than three words entered") if array.size > 3
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

it's best to check on the client side

create `word_couter.js.coffee` in `app/assets/javascripts`

include to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee`

this file `#= require word_couter`

```
$ ->
  $('[name="you_input"]').on "change", ->
    input_size = $(@).val().split " "
    if input_size.length > 3
      ...some code here ....
```

I hope this help!